# computing standard deviation of a raster/tiff in R

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I would like to know that how can a value of standard deviation value can be calculated of a tiff/raster file and how can I find the range of values from it?

Background information:
I have a tiff file of Gross Primary Productivity of Himalayan Region, I would like to know the value of the standard deviation of that tiff file. Lets say the mean of that tiff file is 3.23 and if the standard deviation comes 0.11 , will the range be 3.12-3.34?

I am attaching a raster example:

```
ras1 <- raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

To calculate any statistic from raster, you need to use `[]` like this:

```
> library(raster)
> ras1 <- raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2)))
> xmean <- mean(ras1[])
> xsd <- sd(ras1[])
> xmean
[1] 1.5
> xsd
[1] 0.5477226
```

To get the range, you can probably do

```
> c(xmean - xsd, xmean + xsd)
[1] 0.9522774 2.0477226
```

Comment: I would like to can I carry out, c(xmean-xse, xmean+xse) as well if I am using standard error?

Comment: @HallieSheikh You will have to use the formula for calculating the standard error, but yes.